# jQuery Address, changing a parameter? (deep linking)

Tags: javascript, jquery, deep-linking, jquery-address

I'm using **[jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)** to perform deep linking in an ajax site.

I have multiple arguments like this: `/SomeController/SomeAction#/586?e=5808&tab=#First`

**Q1: How do I change just the "tab" parameter?**
When I do it like this...

```
$("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
    $.address.parameter("tab", ui.tab.hash);
}
```

..the result is: `/SomeController/SomeAction#/586?e=5808&tab=#First#Third`
instead of the desired: `/SomeController/SomeAction#/586?e=5808&tab=#Third`

In the event above the other parameters in the url hash should be considered unknown and must remain as they are.

**Q2: How do I remove a parameter from the url hash?**
Like above but if I want to remove the tab parameter completely.

***Thank you!***

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided has a `tabs` example

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/tabs/#Overview

You can snoop the code with firebug. It looks clean

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but thought id still answer.

You must first set the parameter to `null` to remove it then assign the new value:

```
$.address.parameter('tab', null) 
$.address.parameter('tab', ui.tab.hash)
```